# Editing node.js core files does not work

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how node works and for this reason I changed `/usr/lib/nodejs/fs.js`, the change did not appear to be working as expected, so I added `throw "fasd"; process.exit();` to the beginning of `fs.js`, expecting every other script requiring that module to crash, but it does not happen: `require('fs'); console.log("i don't care");` prints that line successfully.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, `dpkg -L nodejs | grep fs.js$` does not show any other file, I tried searching for `fs.js` in `/usr`, but did not find another fs.js either.

I do realise that changing core files is a no-no, and I'll revert the changes later, but for now I'm trying to find out why my changes are ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently core modules, such as `fs` are compiled into [binary](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules), so I resorted to copying the file and requiring it with `require('./fs')`.